# Is there any way to find what is the default activity transition animation?

Tags: android

I need to changed Layouts in my activity ( lot off them in one activity ). I put animations between like

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
      android:fromXDelta="100%"
      android:toYDelta="0"
      android:duration="300" />
    <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="0.1"
      android:toAlpha="1.0"
      android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

Is there any way to find what is he default activity transition animation on phone ?

Answer (score 1):

By "standard-default animation" you mean the default activity transition animation ? If so, it's phone (or vendor) specific.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Different smart phone manufacturers customize a little bit on the Android OEM version.